Approximating 1 with sums of reciprocals of primes
After perusing some old math assignments, I have been trying to determine whether there is always a finite set of primes $p_1,\cdots,p_k$ together with coefficients $c_1,\cdots,c_k$, each $\pm1$, so that $c_1\tfrac{1}{p_1}+\cdots+c_k\tfrac{1}{p_k}$ is arbitrarily close to 1. From just trying a few specific cases it seems like this should be true, but if proving this requires a fancy analytic observation, I'm not in a position to notice. Surprisingly I can't seem to find anything online about this specific question.

Once you know that the sum of reciprocal sums diverges you can add each $1/p_n$ if the sum so far is less than 1 and subtract if the sum is greater than 1. Because the sum of $1/p_n$ diverges it diverges starting from any $n$, so you can't get stuck away from 1. After the addition or subtraction you are within $1/p_n$ of $1$. As this goes to $0$ you have convergence, or you can go back to the definition of $N−\epsilon$. Give me an $\epsilon$ and I choose N such that $p_n>1/\epsilon$ and we are always within $\epsilon$ of the limit. The argument does not depend on it being $1$ that you want to approximate.

Ok, this is my favorite answer! Crystal clear!

The infinite sum of reciprocals of primes diverges: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/p_n = \infty$. In particular, $1/p_n\to0$.
By Dirichlet test here, considering $c_n$ such that the partial sums are bounded (e.g. $c_n=(-1)^{2n-1}$), we get a conditionally convergent series $\sum_n c_n/p_n$.
By the Riemann series theorem here, you can permute the terms of this series such that you converge to $1$, and thus you get arbitrarily close to $1$ with any finite number of terms. The "set of primes" you are looking for is given by the first few terms of this special rearrangement guaranteed by Riemann series theorem.

Thank you! The calc series was a long time ago for me...

Indeed, you don't need $-1$.  There is an infinite subset $S$ of the primes such that
$\sum_{p \in S} 1/p = 1$.  And then finite truncations of this infinite sum can be arbitrarily close to $1$.
To construct $S$, you can use a greedy approach: look at the primes $p_i$ one by one, and include prime $p_i$ in $S$ if the partial sum (i.e. the sum of $1/p_i$ and the reciprocals of the primes $< p_i$ that have already been chosen to be in $S$) is less than $1$.
